# How do I define a default parameter for a function in a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, autohotkey, optional-parameters

I use AutoHotkey, and I just got into C++ programming, so I want to be able to use C++ code from within AutoHotkey.  My solution for this is to compile the C++ functions I want to use into a DLL using Visual Studio and use `DllCall()` to call them from there.  I'm trying to write a function `fibonacci(n, a, b)` that calculates the *n*th element of the Lucas sequence beginning with *F₁* = a and *F₀* = b.  I want to make a and b optional parameters, such that the function returns the *n*th Fibonacci number if only *n* is passed.  However, when I try to implement the function in a DLL and call it with only one parameter using `DllCall()` from within AutoHotkey, I always get 0 rather than the correct answer, but get the correct answer when I pass arguments for a and b.  Here's my code:

mathlib.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIB_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C" MATHLIB_API __int64 fibonacci(__int64 n, __int64 a, __int64 b);

void fibonacci_recurse(__int64 n, __int64& p, __int64& q);

void fibonacci_recurse_n(__int64 n, __int64& p, __int64& q);
```

mathlib.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "mathlib.h"


__int64 fibonacci(__int64 n, __int64 a = 1, __int64 b = 0) {
    __int64 p = 0, q = 0;
    n < 0 ? fibonacci_recurse_n(n, p, q) : fibonacci_recurse(n, p, q);
    return a * q + b * (p - q);
}

void fibonacci_recurse(__int64 n, __int64& p, __int64& q) {
    if (n == 0) {
        p = 1; q = 0;
        return;
    } __int64 u, v;
    fibonacci_recurse(n >> 1, u, v);
    if (n & 1) {
        p = u * (u + 2 * v);
        q = u * u + v * v;
    } else {
        p = u * u + v * v;
        q = v * (2 * u - v);
    }
}

void fibonacci_recurse_n(__int64 n, __int64& p, __int64& q) {
    if (n == -1) {
        p = 0; q = 1;
        return;
    } __int64 u, v;
    fibonacci_recurse_n(n >> 1, u, v);
    if (n & 1) {
        p = u * (u + 2 * v);
        q = u * u + v * v;
    } else {
        p = u * u + v * v;
        q = v * (2 * u - v);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a limitation of DLLs?

Comment: The quick answer is "don't do this" for functions exported as `C`.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: There is no such thing as default arguments in `C` and for `C` functions.  Second, did you test your code as a non-exported, C++ function?

Comment: I tried writing the function in a program of its own, and got a compile-time error saying that the function didn't take one argument.  I don't know what's going on.  It should be possible to do this.

Comment: You get a compiler error because you told the compiler it is a `C` function.  Default arguments are a `C++` thing, not a `C` thing.

Comment: I removed the ```"C"```.

Comment: Default argument values should be in the [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) of the function, not the definition.

Comment: I just figured that out myself.  It doesn't make the AutoHotkey ```DllCall()``` call work, though.  As a matter of fact, if I exclude the ```"C"```, AutoHotkey doesn't see the function.